# How can we "manually"/explicity define a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

The following is what I will call the "implicit" way to define a class:

```
class Super:
    pass

class Klass1(Super):
    a = 1
    i = 4
    def get_i(self):
        return self.i
```

The following is an attempt to "explicitly" define a class like the one above:

```
get_i = lambda self: self.i    
dct = dict(a=1, i=4, get_i=get_i)    
Klass2 = type('Klass2', (Super,), dct)
```

However, `Klass1` and `Klass2` are not equivalent, as the following test shows:

```
import inspect
import types  
LambdaType = type(lambda:0)    
dollar_param_lines = ['isinstance($, types.LambdaType)',
                      'isinstance($, LambdaType)',
                      '$.__name__',
                      '$.__qualname__',
                      'type($)',
                      'inspect.isfunction($)',
                      'inspect.ismethod($)',
                      ]    
for p_line in dollar_param_lines:
    for kls_name in ('Klass1', 'Klass2'):
        # get_i = getattr(kls, 'get_i')
        unparam_line = p_line.replace('$', kls_name + '.get_i')
        result = eval(unparam_line)
        result = str(result)
        print(unparam_line.ljust(45), result)
```

The output for the distribution of python I am using is:

```
isinstance(Klass1.get_i, types.LambdaType)    True
isinstance(Klass2.get_i, types.LambdaType)    True
isinstance(Klass1.get_i, LambdaType)          True
isinstance(Klass2.get_i, LambdaType)          True
Klass1.get_i.__name__                         get_i
Klass2.get_i.__name__                         <lambda>
Klass1.get_i.__qualname__                     Klass1.get_i
Klass2.get_i.__qualname__                     <lambda>
type(Klass1.get_i)                            <class 'function'>
type(Klass2.get_i)                            <class 'function'>
inspect.isfunction(Klass1.get_i)              True
inspect.isfunction(Klass2.get_i)              True
inspect.ismethod(Klass1.get_i)                False
inspect.ismethod(Klass2.get_i)                False
```

In particular, `__name__` and `__qualname__`  are different. How can we modify the "explicit" class definition I gave earlier so that `Klass2` is essentially a deepy copy of  `Klass2` and vis versa.

Answer (score 2):

You're not seeing any difference in the classes `Klass1` and `Klass2` themselves, only in the functions `Klass1.get_i` and `Klass2.get_i`. So you're asking the wrong question.

To verify that, try defining `Klass2` this way:

```
def get_i(self):
    return self.i
dct = dict(a=1, i=4, get_i=get_i)    
Klass2 = type('Klass2', (Super,), dct)
```

Or, alternatively, defining `Klass` this way:

```
class Klass1(Super):
    a = 1
    i = 4
    get_i = lambda self: self.i
```

You'll see that there is no difference anymore.

---

If you're interested in the difference between `def` and `lambda`, we can strip away all the class stuff and compare:

```
def f(): return 0
g = lambda: 0
```

But now it should be obvious. The `def` statement has a name to store; the `lambda` expression does not. The fact that you happen to store the lambda in a variable named `g` after it's created doesn't matter. You could just as easily have assigned it to two variables, or used it without assigning it, or assigned it to an element of an attribute of a temporary unnamed object. So its name is just `<lambda>`.

If you dig into it further, you'll find that `LambdaType` and `FunctionType` are the same type, and that the only attributes of these functions that differ are `__name__` and `__qualname__`.

Comment: If `Klass1.get_i` and `Klass2.get_i` are different, I consider `Klass1` and `Klass2` to be different.

Comment: @ToothpickAnemone OK, you can define the boundaries however you want. But the difference isn't in the way you defined the classes, it's in the way you defined the functions. So, if you want to understand that difference, or to control it, that's the part you have to look at. And it's also a lot simpler that way: `lambda` doesn't assign a name, for obvious reasons, and… that's basically it (as long as you can write code for both that compiles to the same bytecode, at least).

Answer (score 1):

As you've said, the only difference between the two classes is the `__name__` and `__qualname__` of your `get_i` function. Thus, making the two classes equivalent is as simple as setting those two attributes to the correct values:

```
get_i = lambda self: self.i    
get_i.__name__ = 'get_i'
get_i.__qualname__ = 'Klass2.get_i'
dct = dict(a=1, i=4, get_i=get_i)    
Klass2 = type('Klass2', (Super,), dct)
```

Now the comparison shows the following output:

```
isinstance(Klass1.get_i, types.LambdaType)    True
isinstance(Klass2.get_i, types.LambdaType)    True
isinstance(Klass1.get_i, LambdaType)          True
isinstance(Klass2.get_i, LambdaType)          True
Klass1.get_i.__name__                         get_i
Klass2.get_i.__name__                         get_i
Klass1.get_i.__qualname__                     Klass1.get_i
Klass2.get_i.__qualname__                     Klass2.get_i
type(Klass1.get_i)                            <class 'function'>
type(Klass2.get_i)                            <class 'function'>
inspect.isfunction(Klass1.get_i)              True
inspect.isfunction(Klass2.get_i)              True
inspect.ismethod(Klass1.get_i)                False
inspect.ismethod(Klass2.get_i)                False
```